# UVa Run time error in Python

Tags: python, runtime-error

So I'm trying to solve the following problem from the UVa online judge: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2864

I've written the following code in Python:

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    highs = 0
    lows = 0
    walls = int(input())
    heights = [0]*50
    for h in range(walls):
        heights[h] = (int(input()))
    for j in range(1, walls):
        if (heights[j] < heights[j - 1]):
            highs += 1
        elif (heights[j] > heights[j - 1]):
            lows += 1
    print("Case %d: %d %d" % (i + 1, highs, lows))

exit(0)
```

Every time I try my code with different test cases I get the expected output; it works perfectly fine in my side but when I submit it I keep on getting a Runtime Error. I'm desperate now as I have tried a million things and nothing works. Please, help.

Comment: I get a runtime error is not very helpful ... at a guess the judge uses 2.7 and you wrote it for 3.x

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you provide the `RunTimeError`'s message it will help to see what's going on  - just edit the question and paste it there ;-)

Comment: Thanks @SebasSBM but the online judge doesn't specify which RunTimeError it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
for h in range(walls):
    heights[h] = (int(input()))
```

`input()` reads a line, then`int()` tries to convert the line to an integer. But `"1 4 2 2 3 5 3 4"` cannot be converted to an integer, and if you read 8 lines you will probably run out of input.

Instead, try

```
heights = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

which should return `[1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested the Runtime Error is in this part of your code:

```
for h in range(walls):
    heights[h] = (int(input()))
```

that you can change for

```
heights = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

and omit the line

```
heights = [0]*50
```

Another thing that I found is that you are counting in a contrary manner lows and highs. You should do:

```
    if (heights[j] < heights[j - 1]):
        lows += 1
    elif (heights[j] > heights[j - 1]):
        highs += 1
```

That should work. Hope you get the solution Accepted ;)